# supports_check_mode for non-Python module

Tags: ansible, ansible-2.x

An Ansible module written in Python can [support check mode](http://docs.ansible.com/ansible/developing_modules.html#check-mode) by setting `supports_check_mode=True`:

```
module = AnsibleModule(
    argument_spec = dict(...),
    supports_check_mode=True
)
```

Now I have a 700+ lines Ruby script I'd like to turn into a module and would like to avoid translating it to Python. Is there a way how to support check mode for non-Python modules?

Comment: If I'm not wrong, your module will be called with a set of arguments, one of which will be `check` or `check_mode`. The `supports_check_mode` would only be used to print out `This module does not support check mode`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ansible will pass an argument `_ansible_check_mode` to the module, which is true if you are in check mode.

Remember that the arguments are put in a file, and the path to the file is argument #2.

Here is a PHP example:

./library/test_module.php

```
#!/usr/bin/env php
<?php

// WANT_JSON Causes ansible to store args in JSON

$args = json_decode(file_get_contents($argv[1]), true);

$check_mode = !empty($args['_ansible_check_mode']);

$output = array(
    'changed' => false,
    'checking' => $check_mode
);

echo json_encode($output);
```

Matching playbook:

./test_module.yml

```
---
- hosts: localhost
  gather_facts: no
  become: no
  tasks:
    - test_module:
        key: value
```